# Jasmine test for factory function calling local and another function - getting Error: Expected a spy, but got Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, junit, jasmine

I have a factory which is having two functions and two local methods, I have wrote a jasmine test case in which a way that when `SavePref.saveDetails(values, prop);` is called I need to expect local method `updateDetails` as well as factory function `SavePref.savePref` has been called like as shown below

```
        SavePref.saveDetails(values, prop);
        expect(updateDetails).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(SavePref.savePref).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But the problem is when I run the test case I am getting

```
Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My factory is as given below

```
 app.factory('SavePref', function($rootScope, Restangular) {

            updateFiles = function(prop) {
                if (!prop.found) {
                    _.merge(prop.oldFiles, prop.newFiles);
                }
            };

            updateDetails = function(values, newProp) {
                angular.forEach(values, function(value, index) {
                    newProp.found = false;
                    newProp.datas = value.datas;
                    updateFiles(newProp);
                });
            };

            return {

                savePref: function(newProp) {
                    Restangular.all('rest/savePref').post(newProp).then(function(response) {
                        $rootScope.success = true;
                    }, function(errorResponse) {});
                },

                saveDetails: function(values, prop) {
                    var newProp = {};
                    newProp.values= prop.values;
                    newProp.oldFiles = prop.oldFiles;
                    newProp.newFiles = prop.newFiles;
                    updateDetails(values, newProp);
                    this.savePref(newProp);
                }
            };
        });
```

My Jasmine Test cases

```
describe('Service: SavePref', function(SavePref) {
    beforeEach(module('com'));

    var httpBackend;
    var RestangularMock;

    var values;

    beforeEach(function() {
        values = {
            datas: {
                file1: 'Test1',
                file2: 'Test2',
                file3: 'Test3'
            }
        };
        prop = {
            oldFiles: 'sampleFile1',
            newFiles: 'sampleFile2',
            values: {}
        };

        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('prop', prop);
        });
    });

    describe('Testing saveDetails Functions', function() {
        it('should save details when saveDetails is called', inject(function(SavePref) {

            SavePref.saveDetails(values, prop);
            expect(updateDetails).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(SavePref.savePref).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: You are not creating a spy object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create spy first to expect:

```
it('should save details when saveDetails is called',inject(function(SavePref) {

        spyOn(SavePref, "savePref").and.callThrough();
        SavePref.saveDetails(values, prop);
        expect(SavePref.savePref).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

If you want to expect updateDetails, you will have to make it public.

In my exemple I called `.and.callThrough()` else the call is never made to the actual function. Maybe you will want to delete it.

Comment: I am getting `Error: undefined() method does not exist`

Comment: test,  when I run `grunt ci` I am getting `Error: undefined() method does not exist`

Comment: is it the problem with calling `this.savePref(newProp);` with `this`

Comment: try commenting it and see if there is still a bug.

Comment: when I comment the `spyOn(SavePref.savePref).and.CallThrough();` and `expect(SavePref.savePref).toHaveBeenCalled();` test is executing successfully

Comment: Is `.and.callThrough()` necessary since when I  did `spyOn(SavePref, "savePref");
        SavePref.saveDetails(values, prop);
        expect(SavePref.savePref).toHaveBeenCalled();` It got executed successfully but when I add `.and.callThrough()` test is not executing successfully

Comment: not it's not. As I said it forward the call to the real function with and.callThrough. Most of the time that's not what you want.

Comment: so no need of `and.callThrough` in my case